# OpenMP task construct does not scale with the number of threads

Tags: task, openmp

I am using OpenMP **task** construct to parallelize the execution of a binary tree application. However, the runtime performance shows that single-threaded implementation outperforms multi-threaded implementations. How do I interpret the results?

The implementation is the following:

```cpp
  size_t N = 1 << 16;
  size_t *D = new size_t [N];
  size_t threads = 1;  // 1, 2, 4, 8, 16

  std::vector<std::vector<int>> mat1(128); // a 2D matrix
  std::vector<std::vector<int>> mat2(128); // a 2D matrix

  for(size_t i = 0; i < mat1.size(); ++i){
    mat1[i].resize(128);
    mat2[I].resize(128);
  }

  #pragma omp parallel num_threads(threads)
  {
    #pragma omp single
    {
      for(size_t i = 1; i < N; ++i) {

        size_t p = i / 2;
        size_t l = i * 2;
        size_t r = l + 1;

        if(l < N && r < N) {
          #pragma omp task firstprivate(i) depend(out:D[l], D[r]) depend(in:D[p])
          {
            // perform matrix multiplication
            for(size_t x = 0; x < 128; ++x) {
              for(size_t y = 0; y < 128; ++y) {
                size_t sum = 0;
                for(size_t z = 0; z < 128; ++z) {
                  //sum += mat1[x][z] * mat2[z][y];
                  sum += mat1[x][z] * mat2[y][z]; // mat2 is transposed for better memory access pattern
                }
              }
            }     
          }
        }
        else {
          #pragma omp task firstprivate(i) depend(in:D[p])
          {           
            // perform matrix multiplication
            for(size_t x = 0; x < 128; ++x) {
              for(size_t y = 0; y < 128; ++y) {
                size_t sum = 0;
                for(size_t z = 0; z < 128; ++z) {
                  //sum += mat1[x][z] * mat2[z][y];
                  sum += mat1[x][z] * mat2[y][z]; // mat2 is transposed for better memory access pattern
                }
              }
            }     
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }

  delete [] D;
}
```

However, if I replace the matrix multiplication with sleep. Then the runtime performance does scale with the number of threads.
The following image is the runtime performance of matrix multiplication.
[image: runtime performance graph of matrix multiplication]

The following image is the runtime performance of sleep.
[image: runtime performance graph of sleep]

If I replace the matrix multiplication with a lightweight operation, such as the following:

```
size_t sum = i * 1000 // i is the private value for each task
```

I observe the same runtime performance as the matrix multiplication that OpenMP does not scale. The figure of runtime performance is shown below, [runtime performance graph of a lightweight operation](https://uwmadison.box.com/s/zoilnyt0eqz0kcdtjwmj1l15q5fh422z)

The implementation is compiled with gcc-12 and O3 enabled and ran on a Ubuntu 19.10 (Eoan Ermine) machine with 80 Intel Xeon Gold 6138 CPU at 2.00GHz and 256 GB RAM.

I expect the runtime performance and the number of threads has a convex curve in which the lowest points are either 4 or 8 threads.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [C++ OpenMP doesn't speed up matrix multiplication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77050089/c-openmp-doesnt-speed-up-matrix-multiplication). Put it shortly, `std::vector<std::vector<int>>` is inefficient,  `mat2[z][y]` exhibit an inefficient memory access pattern which likely make the algorithm memory bound (or/and cause cache trashing). Memory bound algorithm does not scale because more core does not help to make the RAM faster (quite the opposite actually with many cores due to contentions).

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Matrix multiplication is just an example. If I replace the matrix multiplication with other light-weight numerical calculations, OpenMP still does not scale. But you are right about the memory access pattern in matrix multiplication.

Comment: Submitting tasks to the runtime is a bit expensive and you do that serially here, so the tasks needs to take a significant time. In general, the overhead of tasks is the order of 1 us so tasks should last >100 us so for the code to scale. Actually, the sequential submission limit the scalability on many-core platforms so tasks should even have a bigger granularity. If the submission is not an issue, then the only possible remaining issue is dependencies (I did not check them, but if a sleep scale, then it is likely that dependencies are not an issue).

Comment: Note that it is not clear what is the unit of time on the graphs (e.g. cycles, ns, µs, ms, seconds). Can you please specify this?

Comment: Please either correct the inefficient access pattern of your code and, or show the alternate code with "lightweight" calculations you are using, and show the new timings. Also, please indicate what is your hardware (which CPU, mainly). Note that "lightweight calculations" are often memory bound, which means poor scaling.

Comment: 1. The vertical axis represents the runtime in us. 2. Sorry for the confusion. The "lightweight" calculation is lightweight compared to matrix multiplication. For example, size_t sum = i * 1000; // where i is a private variable for each task.

Comment: You mean just one multiplication per task in the "lightweight" case? If yes this is a way too small workload and you are only observing the OpenMP overheads to create the tasks.

Comment: @PierU, you are right. That is why I am using a more heavy operation, such as MM, to emphasize the task execution instead of the overhead of task creation and the task scheduling.

Comment: But the point is, your MM code is "flawed" with a poor memory access pattern on `mat2` that results in a lot of cache misses: this is already bad for a serial execution, and it's even worse for a multithreaded execution.

Comment: Thanks for bringing that up. I edited my post and re-ran the experiment and got the same runtime performance result that OpenMP does not scale.

Comment: As previously noted, tasks are very heavy-weight. You should compare against a simple `#pragma omp parallel for`. Probably with `schedule(dynamic)` to compensate for that `if`

Comment: Indeed, I can use parallel for to replace task construct. However, task construct together with depend can define task-execution constraints easily.

Comment: The point is to give you a base-line for what you can achieve w.r.t.parallelization. If a simple construct scales, you know it's not another bottleneck such as memory. FWIW the task construct scales just as well as the `parallel for` loop on my system. Both get 7.5 times faster on an 8 core/16 thread system using 16 threads. Have you tried something like [`OMP_PROC_BIND=close`](https://www.openmp.org/spec-html/5.0/openmpse52.html) or `spread`?

Comment: BTW: Your test results would also be consistent with all threads being bound to the same core, maybe by an external job scheduler such as SLURM or MPI. `sleep` would still "scale" since all tasks can sleep in parallel on the same core but they wouldn't be able to actually run in parallel

Comment: I can see that you have partially corrected your code according to my answer below, but still I'd like some feedback on this answer, thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the comments and suggestions, I posted my findings and my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

I have tested your code and raised two issues:

1. since you don't use at all the results of the calculations, the compiler (I used `g++ -O3 -fopenmp`) simply skips the loops (i.e. doesn't execute them at all), so the timings means nothing. I have introduced some instructions to avoid this issue
2. but then I got segmentation faults: I'm no C++ specialist, but are you sure that your matrices are correctly declared? The outer vector is dimensioned to 128, but the inner vector sizes are unspecified (**edit**: I see that you now corrected your code). I replaced then by classical C 2D arrays and now the code runs fine... and takes much more time.

Here is the modified code:

```cpp
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstddef>
#include <vector>
#include <omp.h>

int main() {

  size_t N = 1 << 10; //16;
  size_t *D = new size_t [N];
  size_t threads = 2;  // 1, 2, 4, 8, 16
  size_t *sum = new size_t [N]; // global sum array to avoid skipping the calculations

  //std::vector<std::vector<int>> mat1(128); // a 2D matrix
  //std::vector<std::vector<int>> mat2(128); // a 2D matrix

  // classical C arrays
  size_t mat1[128][128], mat2[128][128];
  for (int i = 0; i < 128; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < 128; j++) {
      mat1[i][j] = 0;
      mat2[i][j] = 0;
    }
  }

  double tic = omp_get_wtime();

  // number of threads set by the environment variable OMP_NUM_THREADS
  #pragma omp parallel 
  {
    #pragma omp single
    {
      for(size_t i = 1; i < N; ++i) {

        size_t p = i / 2;
        size_t l = i * 2;
        size_t r = l + 1;

        if(l < N && r < N) {
          #pragma omp task firstprivate(i) depend(out:D[l], D[r]) depend(in:D[p])
          {
            // perform matrix multiplication
            //size_t sum = 0;
            for(size_t x = 0; x < 128; ++x) {
              for(size_t y = 0; y < 128; ++y) {
                for(size_t z = 0; z < 128; ++z) {
                  //sum += mat1[x][z] * mat2[z][y];
                  sum[i] += mat1[x][z] * mat2[y][z]; // mat2 is transposed for better memory access pattern
                }
              }
            }  
          }
        }
        else {
          #pragma omp task firstprivate(i) depend(in:D[p])
          {           
            // perform matrix multiplication
            //size_t sum = 0;
            for(size_t x = 0; x < 128; ++x) {
              for(size_t y = 0; y < 128; ++y) {
                for(size_t z = 0; z < 128; ++z) {
                  //sum += mat1[x][z] * mat2[z][y];
                  sum[i] += mat1[x][z] * mat2[y][z]; // mat2 is transposed for better memory access pattern
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }

  double toc = omp_get_wtime();
  printf("%lf\n",toc-tic);

  delete [] D;
  delete [] sum;
}
```

As I said it is much slower, and it scales (the machine has 10 cores):

```
% g++ -O3 -fopenmp mmtask.cpp
% setenv OMP_NUM_THREADS 1 && ./a.out
1.803429
% setenv OMP_NUM_THREADS 2 && ./a.out
1.011750
% setenv OMP_NUM_THREADS 4 && ./a.out
0.475696
% setenv OMP_NUM_THREADS 8 && ./a.out
0.301431
% setenv OMP_NUM_THREADS 16 && ./a.out
0.357968
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the previous discussions and comments, I found OpenMP task can scale under two conditions:

1. The computation loading of each task must be big (>100us). As the overhead of using task construct can not be ignored, the elapsed time of small tasks would be dominated by the creation and scheduling of tasks.
2. Compilers would optimize the computations when OpenMP tasks only perform local computations, such as

```cpp
for(size_t x = 0; x < 128; ++x) {
  for(size_t y = 0; y < 128; ++y) {
    size_t sum = 0;
    for(size_t z = 0; z < 128; ++z) {
      sum += mat1[x][z] * mat2[y][z]; // OpenMP optimizes this out
    }
  }
}
```

To avoid this optimization, we should use a global data storage as PierU suggests,

```cpp
size_t *sum = new size_t[N];

for(size_t x = 0; x < 128; ++x) {
  for(size_t y = 0; y < 128; ++y) {
    for(size_t z = 0; z < 128; ++z) {
      sum[i] += mat1[x][z] * mat2[y][z]; 
    }
  }
}
```

In the following, I post the entire implementation that I used to measure the runtime performance of OpenMP task construct on a binary tree structure. The implementation is modified on the previous comments.
The implementation is compiled with gcc-9 and O3 enabled and ran on a Ubuntu 19.10 (Eoan Ermine) machine with 80 Intel Xeon Gold 6138 CPU at 2.00GHz and 256 GB RAM.

```cpp
#include <omp.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  
  size_t num_layers = 18;
  unsigned num_threads = strtol(argv[1], NULL, 10);
  size_t msize = strtol(argv[2], NULL, 10);
  
  size_t N = 1 << num_layers;

  std::vector<std::vector<int>> mat1(msize);
  std::vector<std::vector<int>> mat2(msize);

  for(int i = 0; i < msize; ++i) {
    mat1[i].resize(msize);
    mat2[i].resize(msize);
  }
  
  for(int i = 0; i < msize; ++i) {
    for(int j = 0; j < msize; ++j) {
      mat1[i][j] = i+j;
      mat2[i][j] = i-j;
    }
  }

  auto beg = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
  
  size_t *D = new size_t [N];

  #pragma omp parallel num_threads(num_threads)
  {
    #pragma omp single
    {
      for(size_t i = 1; i<N; ++i) {

        size_t p = i / 2;
        size_t l = i * 2;
        size_t r = l + 1;

        if(l < N && r < N) {
          #pragma omp task firstprivate(i) depend(out:D[l], D[r]) depend(in:D[p])
          {
            D[i] = 0; 
            for (int x = 0; x < mat1.size(); x++) {
              for (int y = 0; y < mat1.size(); y++) {
                for (int z = 0; z < mat1.size(); z++) {
                  D[i] += mat1[x][z] * mat2[y][z];
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
        else {
          #pragma omp task firstprivate(i) depend(in:D[p])
          {
             
            D[i] = 0; 
            for (int x = 0; x < mat1.size(); x++) {
              for (int y = 0; y < mat1.size(); y++) {
                for (int z = 0; z < mat1.size(); z++) {
                  D[i] += mat1[x][z] * mat2[y][z];
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }

  delete [] D;

  auto end = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();

  std::cout << "Elapsed: " << std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(end - beg).count() << " us\n";

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Regarding point 2: it's not the OpenMP runtimes that skips some calculations, but the compiler itself (g++ here). It analyses the code, and when it can assert that the result of a calculation is neither used or output, then it doesn't compile the calculation at all.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I edited my solution.